# Autocomplete the search in nav list by refresh with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I am working on a search box which works for a list on the navbar,
I want the list could be refreshed while users enter the key words, in another word, there would be only the matched word showed in the list.

here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/x69chen/sbAR6/

I cannot figure out how to reset the list to empty first, and then replace the list only the matched ones.
I tried this

```
    $( "$nav-list123" ).empty();
```

But is does not work. Could anyone gives some hits?
thanks

Comment: It seems that you have a typo. `$` should be `#` I believe.

Comment: @crush i am sorry it was a typing mistake in the question, i tried this `$("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({ $( "#nav-list123" ).empty(); source: source,..` but it does not work

Comment: That code snippet doesn't make any sense. Please post the actual code.

Comment: @crush I just update the codes http://jsfiddle.net/x69chen/sbAR6/2/, could you help me? where to put the empty function while making the search engine works. thanks

Comment: That's invalid JavaScript.

Comment: @crush I am sorry, how to correct it? I am newbie...

Comment: Let me rephrase that. You should study JavaScript more because it seems you lack knowledge on basic concepts

Answer (score 0):

To reset the list:

```
$("#nav-list123").empty();
```

It works for me in the JS fiddle you show.

Comment: He used `$` instead of `#`

Comment: i am sorry I used $("#nav-list123").empty();, it does not work

Comment: is it like this? `$("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
        $( "#nav-list123" ).empty();
        source: source,..`